# How do I get my Stack Panel to stretch all the way across this header?

Tags: wpf, xaml, stackpanel

In the header of my Expander I am trying to place a few buttons. I want these buttons to be on the far right, however any element I add inside the header is reduced to it's minimum size regardless of the horizontal alignment rules.

[image]

```
        <StackPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="4">
        <Expander ExpandDirection="Down" IsExpanded="True" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF3E3D3D">
            <Expander.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock Text="Greeting and Opening" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Button x:Name="GreetingCheckAll_Button" Content="Check All" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander.Header>
```

I want to get that button to the far right instead of to the left, as you can also see the stack panel element is only as large as it needs to be. What do I need to do to allow for the stack panel to stretch across the entire width so I can align the button to the right?

Thanks guys.

Edit: Tried using the docking panel suggestion instead (after looking at the panels overview, that seems the right way to go). I still end up with the same constraints, the panel will not stretch across the entire width of it's parent element unless I manually set it's width in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not a `StackPanel`, you want something like the `DockPanel` or `Grid`

Where you set the first Content as TextBlock, then Dock a button to the right.

Or a Grid.

Comment: To expand a bit, I already have a grid defined above this. Using a dockpanel still results in the same constraints unless I manually set it's width in pixels. Using Grid.ColumnSpan doesn't seem to have an effect on it.